# The Worksheet_Change function runs even for non target cells can it be prevented

Tags: excel, vba

I have two codes one is in a Module and other is in the sheet1. The code in Sheet1 is the Worksheet_Change code. Whenever I am trying to run the code in Module, it gives an error and activates the sheet1 code.

I went through the forum and tried the solutions of specifying target cells for the `Private Sub` and using `EnableEvents = False` solutions. None of this is working. The code in the sheet1 is also not working and executing all the codes together.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)

Dim KeyCell As range

Set KeyCell = range("A1:J1")    

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCell, Me.range(A1)) Is Nothing Then
    OffEmp range("B151:B210"), False

    If range("A1") = "A Off" Then
        OffEmp range("B151:B210"), True
    ElseIf range("A1") = "A" Then
            range("B151:B210").ClearContents
    End If
End If
'After executing the above code it jumps to this code and executes it even when Cell B1 is not changed.

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCell, Target) Is Nothing Then
    OffEmp range("B151:B210"), False
    If range("B1") = "B Off" Then
        OffEmp range("B2:B9"), True
    ElseIf range("B1") = "B" Then
            range("B151:B210").ClearContents
    End If
End If
```

Whenever I am trying to change anything in A1 the code runs and pastes the contents and also clears it at the same time.
The Off range(), False/True is a different Sub as follows:

```
Sub Off(R As range, Off As Boolean)
    With R.Select
             Selection.Copy
         If Off Then
            If IsEmpty(range("$B$151")) = True Then
                    range("$B$151").Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            ElseIf IsEmpty(range("$B$151")) = False Then
                    range("$B$151").Activate
                    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
                    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
                    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The code which I am trying to run as a Module is:

```
Option Explicit
'use a constant to store the highlight color...
Const HIGHLIGHT_COLOR = 9894500 'RGB(100, 250, 150)'Is a cell highlighted? 
EDIT: changed the function name to IsHighlighted

Sub AssignBided()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim cel1 As range
Dim cel2 As range
Dim Bid As range
Dim line As range
Dim Offemp As range
Dim BidL8 As range
Dim BidL8E As range
Dim coresVal As String

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set Bid = ws2.range("$D$12:$D$40, $D$43:$D$58, $D$61:$D$77, $D$81:$D$97, $D$101:$D$117")
Set line = ws2.range("$B$12:$B$40, $B$43:$B$58, $B$61:$B$77, $B$81:$B$97, $B$101:$B$117")
Set Offemp = ws2.range("$B$151:$B$210")
Set BidL8 = ws1.range("$R$27:$R$263")
Set BidL8E = ws1.range("$S$27:$S$263")

For Each cel2 In line
    If IsHighlighted(cel2) Then
        For Each cel1 In BidL8E
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Offemp, cel1.Value) > 0 Then
            Else: cel2.Offset(0, 2).Activate
                    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(Sheet1!$S$27:$S$263,MATCH(" & cel2.Value & ",Sheet1!$R$27:$R$263,0))"
            End If
        Next cel1
    End If
Next cel2
End Sub
Function IsHighlighted(c As range)
    IsHighlighted = (c.Interior.Color = HIGHLIGHT_COLOR)
End Function
```

I am sorry for this long question. But I am in a fix here. Whenever I change cell A1 the code runs and pastes the content as it should, but it also clears it at the same time. ALso when I run the module it executes the code but then triggers the Private Sub when it is trying to paste the name in the cell. Is there any method to make this work? Or any suggestion which will help in this?
Thank you for your efforts in advance.

Comment: `If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCell, Target) Is Nothing Then`

Comment: I made that change but the error is the same! Will the code be affected with multiple `IF` statements?

Comment: Is the selection multiple cells or 1

Comment: `Sub Off(R As range, Off As Boolean)` could cause some problems - you have a procedure and a variable called `Off`.  `Off` also has meaning to VBA - `?Off` in the Immediate window gives a blank line, while `?On` returns `Compile Error`.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Thank you for the suggestion. I changed the name of the Sub to OffEmp but the error is still there. The code is executing but is not just pasting but also clearing the section.

Comment: @urdearboy The selection is for one cell, the above code is for A1:J1, so I have the same If statements for the cells from A1 to J1. If this is what you meant

Comment: "it gives an error" - always helps to describe exactly what error you're seeing and on which line.  It's odd that all of your `Range` are shown as `range` (ie. not proper case) - did you maybe define a variable/procedure/module with name "range" ?

Comment: Good eye @TimWilliams. You might want to and be explicit, e.g. declare as `Excel.Range` instead.

Comment: @TimWilliams I haven't defined any function or sub as range. There is no line error, the code just executes the next line as well even when I have not made any changes to B1. I have updated the code to make more sense.

Comment: What's the purpose of calling the sub `Off` and passing False to the Off parameter ?  It doesn't do anything other tan copy the range, and you can just do that directly...

Comment: `If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCell, Me.range(A1)) Is Nothing Then` is that a typo?    `Me.range("A1")`

Answer (score 1):

Can't you set a public variable say modRun or something to 1 and then in the worksheet, at the beginning of the sub, it checks that variable to see if it's 1 and then exits the sub?
Just make sure to set the variable back to zero at the end of the module.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found a simple but not a short solution to the problem.
I just defined every single target cell as a different variable. It worked since it did not trigger the rest of the code.
It not a really great solution, but serves the purpose that I wanted it to serve.
I am posting the whole code and if someone can help me reduce the number of lines or knows a better way to work on this it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for all your responses and suggestions.

```
'Remove Case Sensitivity
Option Compare Text
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)

Dim KeyCell1 As range
Dim KeyCell2 As range
Dim KeyCell3 As range
Dim KeyCell4 As range
Dim KeyCell5 As range
Dim KeyCell6 As range
Dim KeyCell7 As range
Dim KeyCell8 As range
Dim KeyCell9 As range
Dim KeyCell10 As range
Dim KeyCell11 As range

Set KeyCell1 = range("A1")
Set KeyCell2 = range("B1")
Set KeyCell3 = range("C1")
Set KeyCell4 = range("D1")
Set KeyCell5 = range("E1")
Set KeyCell6 = range("F1")
Set KeyCell7 = range("G1")
Set KeyCell8 = range("H1")
Set KeyCell9 = range("I1")
Set KeyCell10 = range("J1")
Set KeyCell11 = range("Line8_P_Mon, Line10_P_Mon, Line11_P_Mon, Line12_P_Mon")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCell1, Target) Is Nothing Then
    OffEmp range("Off_Mon"), False

    If range("A1") = "A Off" Then
        OffEmp range("A2:A9"), True
    ElseIf range("A1") = "A" Then
            range("Off_Mon").ClearContents
    End If
End If

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCell2, Target) Is Nothing Then
    OffEmp range("Off_Mon"), False
    If range("B1") = "B Off" Then
        OffEmp range("B2:B9"), True
     ElseIf range("B1") = "B" Then
            range("Off_Mon").ClearContents
    End If
End If

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCell3, Target) Is Nothing Then
    OffEmp range("Off_Mon"), False
    If InStr(1, range("C1"), "C Off") > 0 Then
        OffEmp range("C2:C9"), True
    ElseIf range("C1") = "C" Then
            range("Off_Mon").ClearContents
    End If
End If

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCell4, Target) Is Nothing Then
    OffEmp range("Off_Mon"), False
    If InStr(1, range("D1"), "D Off") > 0 Then
        OffEmp range("D2:D9"), True
    ElseIf range("D1") = "D" Then
            range("Off_Mon").ClearContents
    End If
End If

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCell5, Target) Is Nothing Then
    OffEmp range("Off_Mon"), False
    If InStr(1, range("E1"), "E Off") > 0 Then
        OffEmp range("E2:E9"), True
    ElseIf range("E1") = "E" Then
            range("Off_Mon").ClearContents
    End If
End If

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCell6, Target) Is Nothing Then
    OffEmp range("Off_Mon"), False
    If InStr(1, range("F1"), "F Off") > 0 Then
        OffEmp range("F2:F9"), True
    ElseIf range("F1") = "F" Then
            range("Off_Mon").ClearContents
    End If
End If

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCell7, Target) Is Nothing Then
    OffEmp range("Off_Mon"), False

    If InStr(1, range("G1"), "G Off") > 0 Then
        OffEmp range("G2:G9"), True
    ElseIf range("G1") = "G" Then
            range("Off_Mon").ClearContents
    End If
End If

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCell8, Target) Is Nothing Then
    OffEmp range("Off_Mon"), False
    If InStr(1, range("H1"), "H Off") > 0 Then
        OffEmp range("H2:H9"), True
    ElseIf range("H1") = "H" Then
            range("Off_Mon").ClearContents
    End If
End If

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCell9, Target) Is Nothing Then
    OffEmp range("Off_Mon"), False
    If InStr(1, range("I1"), "I Off") > 0 Then
        OffEmp range("I2:I9"), True
    ElseIf range("I1") = "I" Then
            range("Off_Mon").ClearContents
    End If
End If

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCell10, Target) Is Nothing Then
    OffEmp range("Off_Mon"), False
    If InStr(1, range("J1"), "J Off") > 0 Then
        OffEmp range("J2:J9"), True
    ElseIf range("J1") = "J" Then
            range("Off_Mon").ClearContents
    End If
End If
```

There are more lines of code, and All the ranges are named. Thank you.